# Investing Home Insurance Premiums in Exchange for Higher Deductible

Tags: home-insurance

I have recently Feb 2021 paid off my home mortgage. I also have no other debt. My home insurance is $1800 per year with two deductibles based on the Dwelling $284,000.

- Fire = $5400
- Hail and Wind = $8500

Would it be wise for me to lower my premiums for even higher deductible and use the premiums saving for investing.

If I put 5% of the dwelling amount that my deductible will be around 13K per incident but I will save $400 a year which can be invested in mutual funds.

Please let me know how I should proceed?

Comment: This is one of those situations where one has to make a decision b/t risk and reward.  If one were to attain 10% a year from investing, it would take 25 years for that $400 per year to become worth $25k.  Not life changing. I'm risk averse so saving $400 a year isn't worth the added risk.

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes it is wise to increase deductibles and lower premiums *if you can still afford to pay for the deductible*. And it is wise to invest your wealth *so long as you have a large enough emergency fund* and don't have significant debt to deal with.

It would be *wiser* to make sure you have a fully-funded emergency account that is more than the difference in deductible and to deal with any high-interest debt *before* investing. *Don't* treat your investments as an "emergency fund" or invest with high-interest debt.

The risks of putting all of your spare cash in investing is:

- if you happen to have an emergency in a down market, you're "selling low", drastically reducing your overall return.
- You may be tempted to pay for emergencies by other means (borrowing) if you are too emotionally attached to your investments and don;t have enough liquid funds to pay for the emergency.